# Angular 2 VS 2015: Failed to load resource

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

Using VS 2015 .NET core Angular 2 template. Working fine so far, ever since mapped local code to TFS source control problem starts.

Code which is not mapped to tfs source control is working fine. Checked the scenario multiples times mapping with tfs.

Error: Failed to load resource: (at main-client.js or sometimes at vendor.js)

[image: Error: Failed to load resource:]

Comment: 500 is a server error returned form web server, this is nothing to do with TFS or source control I believe. Are you using typescript? how are you bundling your files?

Comment: Checking out the bundled files fixed the issued. May be should not map bundled files to the tfs..